# Java Spring Webflux WebClient from curl with --data-binary @mydata

Tags: java, curl, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Small question regarding converting a curl command to Java Spring Webflux WebClient request please.

I have a very basic and simple curl command:

`curl http://some-host:8080/api/theapi --data-binary @mydata`

Where `mydata` is a file containing a very basic JSON:

```
{
    "somekey": "someValue",
    "anotherkey": "events"
}
```

This is working perfectly fine, I am able to get the payload response with this curl command.
I just want to convert this curl command to Java Spring Webflux WebClient.

Hence, this is what I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var webClient     = WebClient.create().mutate().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create())).build();
        final var jsonPayload          = Map.of("somekey", "someValue", "anotherkey", "events");
        final var response = webClient.post().uri("http://some-host:8080/api/theapi").body(BodyInserters.fromValue(jsonPayload)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

However, I am getting 500, as if the json payload is not understood by the server.

May I ask what is the proper way to pass the equivalent of `--data-binary @mydata` to Webclient please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that means you should send `DataBuffer` within request body and specify the Content Type header `application/octet-stream`

Essentialy `--data-binary` means that you send some binary data within request.

So first you need to convert your object to json-string and after convert this string to DataBuffer

Then specify the header in webclient request spec and insert DataBuffer as publisher into the body using `BodyInserters`

Example:

```
    String json = "your json";
    CharSequenceEncoder encoder = CharSequenceEncoder.textPlainOnly();
    DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    DataBuffer dataBuffer = encoder
            .encodeValue(json, dataBufferFactory, null, null, null);

    final var response = webClient.post()
            .uri("http://some-host:8080/api/theapi")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(BodyInserters
                    .fromDataBuffers(Mono.defer(() ->
                            Mono.just(dataBuffer))
                    )
            )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
```

However, I'm not sure if it works in your case, but just give it a try